# Solving an ODE given a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following ODE:

$$p(t)u''-tu'+u=0$$

Using the fact that $u(t)=t$ is a solution.

I don't know how to begin this....

I tried setting $u=tv$ , and tried solving for $v$,and it have gotten me to the ODE - $2p(t)v'+tp(t)v''−t^2v^2=0$. But I don't know how to continue...

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx

Comment: The standard approach is to take the ansatz $u(t) = t F(t)$ and insert it into the ODE and get an ODE for $F$. This turns out to be a simpler ODE.

Comment: The procedure @Winther suggests has been discussed previously, such as in the Answer to [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626597/solution-to-first-order-linear-ode-and-variation-of-parameters).  If you try the procedure yourself, it will probably be easier to see how it works than to have it explained all over again.

Comment: Setting $u=tv$, and trying solving for $v$, have gotten me to the ODE - $2p(t)v'+tp(t)v''-t^2v^2=0$,,Don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach in this type of problem is based on the use of the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Application_to_linear_differential_equations) of the equation. If $f$ is "the other" solution, then let

$$W(t) = \begin{vmatrix} t & f(t) \\ 1 & f'(t)\end{vmatrix} = t f'(t) - f(t)$$

where $1$ should be viewed as $t'$ (the derivative of $t$).

Notice that

$$p(t) W'(t) =  p(t)[f'(t) + t f''(t) - f'(t)] = t p(t) f''(t) = t [t f'(t) - f (t) ] = t W(t) .$$

Placing ourselves in the neighbourhood of some $t_0$ with $p(t_0) \ne 0$ this means that

$$W' = \frac t {p(t)} W ,$$

which can be immediately integrated to give

$$W(t) = \Bbb e ^{\int \limits _{t_0} ^t \frac 1 {p(s)} \ \Bbb d s} W_0$$

where $W_0$ is a constant that can be determined from the initial conditions.

With this knowledge of $W$ we go back to its formula that we write in the form of a differential equation in $f$:

$$t f' - f = W .$$

As usual, we first study the associated homogeneous equation

$$t f' - f = 0$$

which has the solution $f(t) = Ct$.

Next, using the method of variation of the parameters, we assume that

$$f(t) = C(t) t$$

and plug this into the inhomogeneous equation, to obtain

$$t^2 C'(t) = W(t)$$

which means that

$$C(t) = \int _{t_0} ^t s^{-2} W(s) \ \Bbb d s = \int _{t_0} ^t s^{-2} \Bbb e ^{\int \limits _{t_0} ^s \frac 1 {p(u)} \ \Bbb d u} W_0 \ \Bbb d s$$

whence we finally deduce

$$f(t) = t \int _{t_0} ^t s^{-2} W(s) \ \Bbb d s = W_0 t \int _{t_0} ^t s^{-2} \Bbb e ^{\int \limits _{t_0} ^s \frac 1 {p(u)} \ \Bbb d u} \ \Bbb d s .$$